# RabbitMQ Exchange not found in vhost "/'

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I am trying to set up a retry system in my Rabbitmq setup. In order to achieve this, I have to declare some exchanges, queues and create the necessary bindings between them. So I have something of this nature

```
await subscriber.createExchange('TTL-PAYMENTS', 'direct')
await subscriber.createExchange('DLX-PAYMENTS', 'fanout')
await subscriber.createQueues('payments-retry-1-30s', 'DLX-PAYMENTS', 30000)
await subscriber.createQueues('payments-retry-2-50s', 'DLX-PAYMENTS', 50000)
await subscriber.bindExchanges('payments', 'DLX-PAYMETS')
await subscriber.bindExchanges('payments-retry-1-30s', 'TTL-PAYMETS', 'retry-1')
await subscriber.bindExchanges('payments-retry-2-50s', 'TTL-PAYMETS', 'retry-2')
```

But when I start up the server, I get this error

```
Error: Channel closed by server: 404 (NOT-FOUND) with message "NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'DLX-PAYMETS' in vhost '/'"
```

When I check my rabbitmq management dashboard, I can see that the exchanges and necessary queues are created already. From my understanding, an exchange Is idempotent, meaning that if it doesn't exist it will be created, and if it does exist as long as nothing changes in exchange attributes, the exchange should remain the same. So I am quite confused as to why this is happening. What could I be doing wrong? And how can I rectify this issue? Thank you very much!

Comment: There's clearly a typo with - "DLX-PAYMETS"

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there's a typo with DLX-PAYMETS, missing the N. You have created an exchange named DLX-PAYMENTS.